# could not decode the json of token: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field StandardClaims.aud of type string

Tags: kubernetes, openid

I am getting the error message

```
error: error: could not get a token from the cache or provider: error while authentication: invalid token and you need to remove the cache: could not decode the json of token: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field StandardClaims.aud of type string
```

on kubectl when accessing my kubernetes cluster which has authentication through OpenID enabled.

When I delete the local OpenID token, everything will work fine again, but just once. Then the error message comes back.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Best regards,
rforberger

Comment: It looks like whoever is giving you that token is returning one with an array in the audience field, instead of a string. According to the JWT RFC, that is allowed, but whatever library kubectl is using (sounds like  https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go) does not support it. Technically, it is a kubectl bug.

Comment: @BurakSerdar thanks for this info. Should I upgrade my jwt-go installtion or my OS maybe? I am using kubectl 1.16.x.

Comment: Filing an issue with k8s might be the best solution. They may already have a workaround.

Comment: The problem disappeared without intervention, I don't understand it.

Comment: You probably got a new token from oidc provider with a string value for aud token.

Comment: Maybe, but as far from my knowledge, there were no changes to the oidc provider.